# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonPing'

Tags: spring-cloud, ribbon, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-actuator

I am getting Below Error in production, But in Uat Environment Everything works fine, when calling internal service call i am getting this issue

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonPing' defined 
in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'ribbonPing' parameter 0; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonClientConfig' 

 defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
 Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig]: Factory method 'ribbonClientConfig' threw exception;
 nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Property token.secretekey is invalid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getContext(SpringClientFactory.java:131)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:121)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClientConfig(SpringClientFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory.create(CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.lbClient(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:82)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:108)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.sendImmediateCommonNotification(Unknown Source)
    at com.oppo.finance.serviceimpl.OtpServiceImpl.generateOtp(OtpServiceImpl.java:262)
    at com.oppo.finance.serviceimpl.UserServiceImpl.sentOtp(UserServiceImpl.java:1361)
    at com.oppo.finance.controller.UserController.sendOtp(UserController.java:989)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonClientConfig' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig]: Factory method 'ribbonClientConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Property token.secretekey is invalid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 70 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig]: Factory method 'ribbonClientConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Property token.secretekey is invalid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 84 more
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Property token.secretekey is invalid
    at com.netflix.client.config.DefaultClientConfigImpl.loadProperties(DefaultClientConfigImpl.java:589)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration.ribbonClientConfig(RibbonClientConfiguration.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$188ace4.CGLIB$ribbonClientConfig$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$188ace4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$202b49e2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$188ace4.ribbonClientConfig(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 85 more




    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonPing' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'ribbonPing' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonClientConfig' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig]: Factory method 'ribbonClientConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Property token.secretekey is invalid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What is token.secretekey? It says it's invalid

Comment: It's already in the stacktrace ```Property token.secretekey is invalid```. Check the value of this property.

Comment: token.secrete key is a default property which is used by ribbon client. It is predifined property not user defined .